# Vue-router Getting dynamic path from routes in this.$route.matched

Tags: vue-router

I’m trying to create a breadcrumb using `this.$route.matched`

An example path: `/projects/:projectId/project-details`

So the `this.$route.matched` array has 3 route objects:

```
Route 1 path: /projects
Route 2 path: /projects/:projectId
Route 3 path: /projects/:projectId/project-details
```

When I print to the console the route path, it doesn’t interpolate the dynamic `:projectId` and instead prints out `/projects/:projectId`.

Is there any way to get the dynamic `:projectId` interpolated in the path in a non-hacky way?

Basically I want to set up a router-link where `:to="routePath"`, where `routePath` is `"/projects/33"` instead of `"/projects/:projectId"`.